# open the image from a gallery

Tags: android

i m following the helloGallery tutorial but i would like to open the image when i click it instead of present a toast with the position of the image...any help?this is my code,that presents the position:

```
  g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloGallery.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial shows how to do what you're looking for:
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example/